# Unable to Create Google Cloud Console Project

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm attempting to create my first Google Cloud project, however, after I enter the project name and project id (as per instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/signup#activate)) I receive the following error:

> "Error
>
> Cloud Console has not been activated for your account. Your account
>   may be suspended or disabled. If you are a Google Apps user, ask your
>   domain administrator to enable Apphosting Admin on your account."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Create a Project in Google Developers Console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114798/how-to-create-a-project-in-google-developers-console)

Comment: This answer below refers to an old version of the console, see suggested duplicate above for the current version and its answer.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I found it! Holy crap that was hard.

1. Go into your domain administration @ https://admin.google.com/AdminHome
2. Click the "More controls" link at the bottom the page
3. Within the panel that reveals, click "Other Google Services"
4. Scroll down to "Google App Engine Admin Console" (jet engine w/ wings)
5. Click the name (don't check it, that won't do anything)
6. Under the logo, change the setting from "Off" to either "On for everyone" or "On for some organizations"
7. Confirm your choice

The pop-up claims that it'll take up to 24 hours for the change to propagate, but I was able to successfully create a new application in cloud.google.com within 5 minutes.

This whole experience demonstrates how Google either doesn't care about this market and has ceded it to Amazon or has a totally inept product team working on it.

Comment: Holy crap indeed! Thanks, I was banging my head trying to find it too.

Comment: I'd've never found that without this. You're a lifesaver. :)

Comment: Wow. We're not using Google App Engine so I completely ignored that setting while searching for it. Thanks for figuring it out. Completely agree with your last statement.

Comment: Spent 60 minutes trying to create marketplace account in the old google chrome marketplace which was redirected to from a google sample code.

Comment: It didn't even take me 5minutes for this to propagate to my account. It was probably 30seconds and I was able to create a new project. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: If you are trying to access the Google Play Developer Console you also need in the your Admin Console to go to "More Google Apps"->"Google App Engine Admin Console". Ensure that it is turned on. Then click on the page title "Google App Engine Admin Console" that is actually a drop-down and then select the "Google Play Developer Console" and also enable that.

Comment: I'm trying to now and `Other Google Services` (your Step 3) does not exist on my Admin Panel.

Comment: As an update to the new dashboard, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114798/how-to-create-a-project-in-google-developers-console

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution: In our Google Apps domain settings, it was necessary to enable the service "Google App Engine Admin Console"

Answer (score 0):

I received the same initial error message. I quickly copy and pasted the message into a google search and found this post. I went to follow the instructions for the top answer on this post, but google wouldn't let me log in or there was some weird loop of logging in and then selecting which google account to log in with. I then navigated back to my developer account and then my new project was created and selected in the list of projects. Note that, unlike the original poster, I had already had three existing projects, don't know if that makes a difference, but I'm sure it's possible. Here's a pic so you may see exactly what I'm referring to. As you can see, the project I was trying to create is called 'Neighborhood Map Project' and is selected from the project list dropdown. I feel like I dodged a bullet here and saved myself two hours of fiddling around and I wanted to share my experience with you all so that you may quickly resolve your problem like I did.

Cheers

[image: Screenshot of my google dev console]