# Google developer console disabled

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-messaging

I have created a developer account on **Google** in order to publish an android app on **Google Play**. After some time I needed GCM, but I cant be able to get a API key. I am able to enter [developer console](https://cloud.google.com/console#/project), but when I try to create a new project I get an error as following:

```
ERROR
Developers Console has not been activated for your account. Your account may be suspended or disabled. If you are a Google Apps user, ask your domain administrator to enable Apphosting Admin on your account.
```

I have been sent no email about if my account was banned or not. I have posted an email to google support but they did not respond yet(not sure if they care). What should I do? How to find why I am banned from creating a project on **Developer Console**.

When I try to access some pages I have been redirected to [this error page](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/40039?p=devconsole). This is where I have sent email.

Comment: refer this...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314755/unable-to-create-google-cloud-console-project

Comment: @rohan it says 
"Sign into a different account to access Google Admin" on the very first step. Sorry, did not work.

Answer (score 14):

From [here][1]:

1. Go into your domain administration @ https://admin.google.com/AdminHome
2. Click the "More controls" link at the bottom the page
3. Within the panel that reveals, click "More Google Apps"
4. Select checkbox for "Google Developers Console" (hexagon nut logo)
5. In the top-left you will see an icon to "Turn ON services"
6. Confirm your choice

Comment: This does not work. Step 6 has no settings on my account. Are there any ways to get my account to work like yours @MarkCarter?

Comment: @H.Ferrence I have just updated my answer. Please check if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @MarkCarter ... here's how it worked for me -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114798/how-to-create-a-project-in-google-developers-console

Comment: Thank you, works for me. I could not manage to work out how to do this. I had been looking in 'add services' under apps.

Comment: Well, google says:  `You need to use a Google Apps account to log into Google Admin Console.`since the problem is not about Google Apps I guess.

Comment: It looks like "Google Developer Console" may have been renamed to "Google Cloud Platform" in the list. Still has the same hexagon logo.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently Google has changed the flow since this was answered.

I had to:
1) Go to this page via App Settings > Additional Google Services
https://admin.google.com/AdminHome#AppsList:serviceType=ADDITIONAL

2) Look for the "Develop applications using Google APIs and the Google Cloud Platform" setting

3) Click the vertical ... in the right hand corner of the row and select "ON for everyone"

Make sure you are logged in with the Admin account for your domain.  If you are redirected to "https://apps.google.com/user/hub" then you are not an admin.

Comment: The problem is: I wasn't a Domain Admin since the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

**Enable Google Developer Console** for **G Suite** (Google Apps)

1. [admin.google.com](http://admin.google.com)
2. Select: **Apps** (*Manage apps and their settings*)
3. Select: **Additional Google services** (*Blogging, photos, ...*)
4. (bottom right corner you'll find **Page 1 of 6**, switch pages to locate Google Developers Console)
5. Check: **Google Developers Console** and select **ON** in top right corner
6. Confirm with **TURN ON**

[image]

Comment: google shows following error on the very first step:

`admin.google.com is for G Suite accounts only. Regular Gmail accounts cannot be used to sign in to admin.google.com`

Comment: Regular Gmail accounts will have this app enabled by default

Answer (score 0):

You should ask your domain administrator to enable Apphosting Admin on your account.

Comment: what happens if you, yourself, are the Domain Administrator? Then what @alpan?