# How to Create a Project in Google Developers Console

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am trying to create a project in Google Developers Console.

Note: I am the Domain Administrator.

I keep getting this error message;

**Error**

**Developers Console has not been activated for your account. Your account may be suspended or disabled. If you are a Google Apps user, ask your domain administrator to enable Apphosting Admin on your account.**

**See my steps to produce the error (screen shots):**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bytqhoir_Tt5QmFTazM0SzZONU0/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bytqhoir_Tt5c3BwSnA3bThCSXc/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bytqhoir_Tt5SVZZWTRfQVBTRUk/view?usp=sharing

Can anyone share some light on how to solve this issue? Please note that I am the domain administrator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google developer console disabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938728/google-developer-console-disabled)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to enable the Cloud Console for your domain or at least the organizational unit that your user is in.

1. Go to your domain's Control Panel : https://admin.google.com
2. Click on the "More Google Apps" button. It might be in the "More Controls" section at the bottom of the screen.
   [image: The More Google Apps button]
3. In the next screen, click on the "Filters" button and uncheck "Show top featured services"
   [image: Show all the services]
4. Once done, the list of service will get quite big. Look for "Google Developers Console", click on it.
   [image: Select the Google Developers Console service]
5. Enable the service
   [image: Enable the service]

Comment: HOLY CR*P @David. You are a super, super-star. That's what I have been looking for since last Friday. Why, why, why does Google make things so overly complicated and hard to find?

Comment: Wow, I am making progress now. I have been spinning my wheels for over 4 days now. This was the needle in the haystack. It would have been awesome if Google could have added a link or some better instructions in the pop-up error box for creating a new project. All it said was contact the domain administrator. But I am the domain administrator. THANKS AGAIN @David -- you saved me from the great pain and agony I've been in.

Comment: Not sure if my domain has a newer or older version of the admin console, but it's moved slightly from the above answer: From the Admin home screen, click Apps, then Additional Google Services.  Then you can pick up starting at step 3.

Comment: Andrew, your tip helped me out.

Comment: This answer needs to be updated to coincide with @Andrew 's feedback

Answer (score 12):

It seems to have changed slightly. I had to go to **Apps**

Then click the **Additional Google Services**

Then you can find **Google Developers Console** in there

And then you can Enable the service by selecting **ON for everyone**

Comment: You sir (or madam), are a gentleman (or woman) and a scholar. Thank you.

Comment: Odd, I don't even see that as an option to select. It's just missing.