# How to Connect to a Google Public Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to build a script to retrieve all my events using the *new* Google Calendar API v3 since Google deprecated v1 and v2 on 11/17/2014.

I am receiving this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with
>   message 'Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/MY-PUBLIC-CALENDAR/events:
>   (403) Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use
>   requires signup.' in
>   /usr/local/lib/php/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php:76
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /usr/local/lib/php/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php(41):
>   Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request)) #1
>   /usr/local/lib/php/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php(548):
>   Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client),
>   Object(Google_Http_Request)) #2
>   /usr/local/lib/php/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Resource.php(190):
>   Google_Client->execute(Object(Google_Http_Request)) #3
>   /usr/local/lib/php/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Calendar.php(1561):
>   Google_Service_Resource->call('list', Array, 'Google_Service_...') #4
>   /home/sme/public_html/app/mods/googleCalendar_3.0/cache_events.php(71):
>   Google_Service_Calendar_Events_Resource->list in
>   /usr/local/lib/php/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php on
>   line 76

Does the `(403) Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded` mean I can no longer test and troubleshoot my script today? Really?

How long do I need to wait to resume working?
What's the workaround?
Why would Google stop us from building a script?

Comment: (403) Daily Limit for Unauthenticated - Means that you are running it with a "public" autentication access instead of hooking it to your project in developer console.  Can you post the code?

Comment: Yep...code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135093/which-php-script-file-is-needed-for-ical-class-in-google-calendar-php-api-v3 Thanks @DaImTo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the Google APIs let you access them using a public non authenticated user.  It is not hooked to a project on Google Developer console due to that fact there is a very strict limit to how much data you can request from it.

`(403) Daily Limit for Unauthenticated` - Means that you are running with that. non authenticated user.  You need to fix your code to use a client id from Google Developer console.