# Unable to create a new project due to limitations to enable cloud services for my organization

Tags: service, cloud, project

I need to figure out how to enable my Google Super Admin account or figure out why Google Cloud Platform service have been disabled. The message says to contact my administrator to turn the service on in the Google Workspace Admin console but I thought I was the admin. I am the only one who has controlled my account. Not sure where to go to enable cloud services so I can create a project. Thanks.

I found this old post that I thought might solve this but I thin some things have changed so it no longer applies. [Unable to Create Google Cloud Console Project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20314755/19267799)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are the admin you can go to `admin.google.com` > `Apps` > `Additional Google services` > `Google Cloud Platform`.

In case you have no access to the service at all you need to check the `Service status` for your user.

[image]

If you are just unable to create projects then in the same page go to `Cloud Resource Manager API settings` and mark the option to allow users to create projects.

[image]

References:

- [Turn Google Cloud Platform on or off for users](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9197205)

Comment: Thank you, Fernando! Very simple and easy steps. It was the Cloud Resource Manager API settings that were not checked. I had to do a search for the Cloud Resource Manager API settings as it was not showing up on the same page. Once I did the search, it showed up.